# Display an image that's stored locally

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I'm using the following code from Three20 to display a photo/image gallery. Can anyone help with changing the code to display an image that's locally stored on the phone instead of on a web server?

```
[[[MockPhoto alloc]
  initWithURL:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3444/3223645618_13fe36887a_o.jpg"
  smallURL:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3444/3223645618_f5e2fa7fea_t.jpg"
  size:CGSizeMake(320, 480)
  caption:@"This is a caption."] autorelease],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a data base  table on which you store the image after been changed to an NSData object

Comment: thanks. I've heard that storing images as blob data in a table is not recommended. I only have 50 images though. maybe for many images it's not recommended.

Comment: maybe ,but as i know this is the common use